# How do I segment the elements iterated over in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I need to loop through an entire list of users, but need to grab 20 at a time.

```
foreach (var student in Class.Students.Take(20))
{
   Console.WriteLine("You belong to Group " + groupNumber);
   groupNumber++;
}
```

This way the first 20 will belong to Group 1, the second 20 to Group 2, and so on.

Is Take the correct syntax for this? I believe Take will take 20 then be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var grouping in Class.Students.GroupBy(s => ++i / 20))
    Console.WriteLine("You belong to Group " + grouping.Key.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks MikeP! That's very helpful. If I needed to assign a particular value to each student in a group, how would I do that? I feel I'm going to have to do a nested for each at some point.

Comment: The grouping object is also enumerable for the elements grouped into it. So just a foreach(var student in grouping) should do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't this code have an off-by-one error because of the pre-increment? In essence, you're iterating starting from `i = 1` instead of 0. For example, if you had a group size of 2, then the first element of the enumerable would be in the first grouping all by itself, since `(0 + 1) / 2 == 0` but `(1 + 1) / 2 == 1`.

Answer (score 11):

For a similar problem I once made an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ToChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int chunkSize)
{
    int itemsReturned = 0;
    var list = enumerable.ToList(); // Prevent multiple execution of IEnumerable.
    int count = list.Count;
    while (itemsReturned < count)
    {
        int currentChunkSize = Math.Min(chunkSize, count - itemsReturned);
        yield return list.GetRange(itemsReturned, currentChunkSize);
        itemsReturned += currentChunkSize;
    }
}
```

Note that the last chunk may be smaller than the specified chunk size.

**EDIT**
The first version used `Skip()/Take()`, but as Chris pointed out, `GetRange` is considerably faster.

Comment: GetRange is 4000+ times faster than Skip/Take

Comment: Hey, thanks @ChrisGessler. It's embarrassing to find oneself overlooking the existence of a "good old" method that does a better job (while I always say to myself that linq is not the answer to everything). In a benchmark with large numbers and non-primitive objects I found a 10+ improvement of GetRange over `Skip()/Take()`. Good call.

Comment: @GertArnold It's a really old answer but can you also provide an async version of this as response to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66321310/convert-non-async-linq-extension-method-to-async

Answer (score 0):

You could project the group number onto each item in the original list using `Select` and an anonymous type like this:

```
var assigned = Class.Students.Select(
  (item, index) => new 
  { 
    Student = item, 
    GroupNumber = index / 20 + 1 
  });
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
foreach (var item in assigned)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Student = " + item.Student.Name);
  Console.WriteLine("You belong to Group " + item.GroupNumber.ToString());
}
```

Or if you wanted to pick off a particular group.

```
foreach (var student in assigned.Where(x => x.GroupNumber == 5))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Name = " + student.Name);
}
```

Or if you wanted to actually group them to perform aggregates

```
foreach (var group in assigned.GroupBy(x => x.GroupNumber))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Average age = " + group.Select(x => x.Student.Age).Average().ToString());
}
```

Now if you just want to lump the items in batches and you do not care about having the batch number information you can create this simple extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, int size)
{
  var assigned = target.Select(
      (item, index) => new
      {
          Value = item,
          BatchNumber = index / size
      });
  foreach (var group in assigned.GroupBy(x => x.BatchNumber))
  {
      yield return group.Select(x => x.Value);
  }
}
```

And you could use your new extension method like this.

```
foreach (var batch in Class.Students.Batch(20))
{
  foreach (var student in batch)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Student = " + student.Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: You made the same mistake as many other posters who have since deleted their responses. You don't take 20 items in a row; each of the first twenty students will all be in a different group!

Comment: Additionally, you're not actually grouping anything either. If you want to iterate the students in a group, your method leaves you high and dry.

Comment: @MikeP: Yep, nice catch. Fixed. I also renamed `grouped` to `assigned` to better reflect what actually happens. If the OP really wanted to iterate students from a particular group you could do `assigned.Where(x => x.GroupNumber == value)` or `assigned.GroupBy(x => x.GroupNumber)`, though that doesn't look necessary based on what I see in the question. I guess one fun aspect of LINQ is that there are a lot of ways of doing the same thing. Anyway, yeah, I totally choked on the `%` thing instead of `/`.