# Split string with Pipe for a chunk in simplest way?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Got a string let say

```
string mystring = "A\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF\nG\n"
```

want to convert it with | for chunk of 5

```
string Converted string ="ABCDE|FG"
```

Any one liner solution..

I am going this way

```
private void TweakInputLines(string InputData)
{
     List<string> lstInput = new List<string>();
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputData))
     {
          lstInput = InputData.Split('\n').ToList();
          if (lstInput.Count > 4)
          {

          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Any effort so far? Did you search `String.Split`? What is the pattern for putting `|` in your string? Is it always after `5` character? What is `lstInput.Count > 9999` for exactly?

Comment: My bad ..updated it ....But looking for any one liner

Comment: convert into char array and then apply a proper logic.

Comment: Is it possible to have `A\nBC\nDEF\nG\nH\nI\nJKL`? What is the result in such case?

Comment: Splitting an IEnumerable in chunks is a common problem for which you can use an extension method like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852288/861716).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution (preserving variable length lines):

```
string input = "A\nBC\nDEF\nG\nH\nI\nJKL\nMN\nO\nP\nQR\nS";
string output = string.Join("|", input.Split('\n')
                                      .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                                      .GroupBy(p => p.i / 5)
                                      .Select(g => string.Join("", g.Select(p => p.s))));
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGH|IJKLMNOP|QRS
```

**Update**

If you use .Net 3.5, then you need to add `.ToArray()` calls in `string.Join()` methods.

```
string input = "A\nBC\nDEF\nG\nH\nI\nJKL\nMN\nO\nP\nQR\nS";
string output = string.Join("|", input.Split('\n')
                                      .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                                      .GroupBy(p => p.i / 5)
                                      .Select(g => string.Join("", g.Select(p => p.s).ToArray()))
                                      .ToArray());
```

**Update 2**

Another option is to use slightly modified solution by @SriramSakthivel

```
string input = "A\nBC\nDEF\nG\nH\nI\nJKL\nMN\nO\nP\nQR\nS";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"((?:.*\n){4}.*)\n", "$1|").Replace("\n", "");
```

Comment: ..This is exactly i am looking for ..but have you tested it its giving me error...compile time

Comment: @RahulChowdhury What kind of compile error? Do you use .Net 3.5?

Comment: Am missing something? OP asked for chunk of 5 but this is not.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel These are chunks of 5 items, not chunks of 5 symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one liner

```
string mystring = "A\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF\nG\n";
var result = Regex.Replace(mystring.Replace("\n", ""), ".{5}", "$0|");
```

Here is the [demo](http://ideone.com/c1PVQG).

Answer (score 0):

Simple code is

```
private void TweakInputLines(string InputData)
    {
        List<string> lstInput = new List<string>();
        var returnstring = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputData))
        {
            lstInput = InputData.Split('\n').ToList();
            if (lstInput.Count > 9999)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (var eachcharitem in lstInput)
                {
                    counter++;
                    returnstring = returnstring + eachcharitem;
                    if (counter == 5)
                    {
                        returnstring = returnstring + "|";
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is what i was doing was looking for a simple one liner

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with the use of Linq - its more or less a "one-liner":

```
string mystring = "A\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF\nG\n";

var str = mystring
           .Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })    // insert Index    
           .GroupBy(i => (int)(i.Index / 5))                                  // group by index / 5
           .Select(value => String.Join("",value.Select(temp => temp.Value))) // create string out of grouped chars
           .Aggregate((a,b) => a + "|" + b);                                  // create one string out of splitted chars 
                                                                              // and join the "|"-string in between
```